# CloudKit with Swift ToDo List App - How do I populate Table View with iCloud Public and Private Database Information

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, xcode7, cloudkit

I am a beginner Apple Developer.

I am having trouble displaying the CloudKit database information on my tableview. I have two Swift files, one connected to the add task view controller, and one connected to the view tasks view controller with a tableview (not a table view controller). I have 3 labels in my cell and I need to display the different database fieldnames correctly with the designated label for that field name. For example, taskName database field info needs to be displayed on the taskName label, taskType database field info needs to be displayed on the taskType label and taskDate database field info needs to be displayed on the taskDate label. I have successfully been able to insert information from the ToDo list app into the public and private Tasks database. I just now need to populate my view controller's table view with the information from the iCloud Tasks database I created.

I don't have code because I don't know how to approach this. First time using CloudKit.

Thank you in advance for responses.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest keeping local copy of the data. Internet connection is not always available, iCloud is not 100.0% available either and its speed may go down and impact your user experience. I believe Apple app review team may not like app that relies on the Internet entirely, if there are other options, either.

Once you have the local copy, you have two things to resolve: How to connect your UITableView, which is easy, and second, how to synchronize data between iCloud and your local copy or copies.

Comment: I have a local SQLite Database working. This is just the iCloud aspect private and public database records. How do you synchronize data between iCloud and the SQLite db? Can I email you? I really need some detailed help walking through this since I'm still very new to programming and Apple development.